# Students - Courses. How to allow to set days of class in initialize method of class Course? Method parameters. Ruby

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am currently working on a Student -  Courses program. Everything was going well until I found myself struggling to understand who to allow my initialize method to have a parameter `days` which values could be any of the days of the week `:mon, :tue, ...`

To be more specific, what I am struggling with is, where and how should I include the list of days of the week that can be included in the initialize parameter of my `class Course`

This is how my class Course looks like so far:

```
    class Course

  attr_reader :department, :name, :credits, :time_block, :days, :students

  def initialize(course_name, department, credits, time_block = nil, days = nil)  # where should I include the list of symbols : :mon,:tue,:weds ... ?? , also time_block? 
    @course_name = course_name
    @department = department
    @credits = credits
    @students = []
    @days = days
    @time_block = time_block
  end


  def name
    @course_name
  end

  def department
    @department
  end

  def credits
    @credits
  end

  def add_student(student)
    return if @students.include?(student)
    student.enroll(self)
  end

  def conflicts_with?(course2)
    return false if self.time_block != course2.time_block

    days.any? do |day|
      course2.days.include?(day)
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: You can have `DAYS = [:mon, :tue, :wed, :thu, :fri, :sat, :sun].freeze` in your `Course` model.
Is there anything specific you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you @Anurag . Yes, I didn't know how and where to add the list of the days of the week so it can be used as a parameter in my initialize method.

Comment: :/ How do I allow the method to take a set of days??

Comment: Pass the new instance a days-array?

Comment: 1. `attr_reader :name, :department, :credit` creates getter methods for those three instance variables, so your redefinition of those getters is superfluous.  2. Consider changing the body of `add_student` to `student.enroll(self) unless students.include?(student)`. Note this uses the getter `:students`. 3. The first statement of `:conflicts_with?` could be written `return false unless time_block == course2.time_block;`. `self` is implicit and `unless` may be preferred because it avoids the negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Course
  attr_reader :days
  def initialize(days)
    @days = days
  end
end

course = Course.new([:mon, :tue, ...])
```

Yep, it's that simple.

Comment: oh wow!! Thank you so much @Huy Vo. Yes, it is very simple. I'm just very new!!